# Android Facebook Integration Issue in Referencing

Tags: android, android-facebook

Successfully imported facebook sdk into my eclipse.but there is an issue in referencing facebook sdk into my own project.trying to referencing facebook sdk like this Project->properties->Android->ADD.when i click Add Facebook is not  listing in project list.what i am doing wrong?please help me!
Here is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the SDK as library .

1. Right click on facebook SDK and then go to properties.
2. Select "Android" tab from left panel.
3. There will be checkbox as "Is library"

check it and apply . It will solve your issue